# Buggy behavior of EllipticK with arbitrary precision input and $MinPrecision

Tags: bugs, special-functions, arbitrary-precision

**Bug introduced in 11.0.0 or earlier, persisting through 11.1.1 or later and fixed in 13.2.0 or earlier**

---

I have encountered weird buggy behavior of `EllipticK` with arbitrary precision input and when $MinPrecision is set. Consider the following code:

```
$MinPrecision = 1;
kr = 0.7`90;
test[k_] := Pi/EllipticK[k]
test[kr]
test[kr]
```

When I evaluate this the first test[kr] evaluates fine and produces the correct answer. However the second evaluation produces a `Divide::infy` error message (and incorrectly returns 0).
Occurrence of this error seems extremely sensitive. It seems to only occur with $MinPrecision set to a non-zero value, `kr` have sufficiently high precision (but not too high), and oddly enough only with a factor Pi appearing in the numerator.

Also, it seems to be version specific, as I never encountered similar issues previously (running the same code on older versions of Mathematica). Current version:

```
"11.0.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (September 20, 2016)"
```

Do others confirm this behavior? If so, on what versions?

**update**
This bug seems to have some seriously nasty behavior. The following codeblock produces an error (and wrong output):

```
$MinPrecision = 1;
ClearSystemCache[];
elK = EllipticK[0.7`90]
Pi/elK
EllipticK[0.7`90]
```

whereas

```
$MinPrecision = 1;
ClearSystemCache[];
elK = EllipticK[0.7`90]
1/elK
EllipticK[0.7`90]
```

is fine. This extremely disturbing since the bug can be triggered in future operations that do not involve `EllipticK` (but only its output). This makes it hard to build effective workarounds.

Comment: Seems to have been introduced in version 11; versions 8 and 10 do not have this issue. As a workaround, use `test[k_] := 2 ArithmeticGeometricMean[1, Sqrt[1 - k]]` instead.

Comment: I would be most grateful if somebody could try this on 11.0.2.

Comment: Could somebody with the latest version (11.1.1?) installed check if this has been fixed? (Else we should flag this as a bug.)

Comment: It seems to be fine in 11.1.1.

Comment: I update to "11.1.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (April 18, 2017)" today, but the problem persists.

Comment: @J.M. You reported that this seemed fine in 11.1.1. However, 11.1.1 still has the problem on my machine. Could you clarify what version you were using?

Comment: Hmm, I believe I had omitted `$MinPrecision = 1;` when I had previously tried it out. Remind me again why you need to put that one in?

Comment: `$MinPrecision = 1` is here as a MWE. It seems to happen for any non-zero value. (The real world applications where this affects me typically have it set higher)

Comment: OK, but why do you need to set it in the midst of evaluating this function? It does look like a bug, sure, but the workaround seems apparent in at least this case.

Comment: You do not need to set it each time. The bug occurs as long as `$MinPrecision` has a non-zero value. There typically is no particular need to have it set while evaluating the elliptic functions. However, the elliptic functions may be called as part of some procedure/function that requires `$MinPrecision` to be set.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes things get upgraded and when things are upgraded, they work better. This is one of those times

[image: screenshot]