# Buggy behavior of EllipticE[0,k] with arbitrary precision input

Tags: bugs, special-functions

I am having an issue where if I provide the EllipticE function with a first argument of zero and a second argument with a precision lower than that of machine precision, the kernel crashes.

For example, EllipticE[0, 0.8`7] and EllipticE[0, 0.6`9], both crash the kernel anytime they are run.

I know there has been issues applying arbitrary precision numbers to Elliptic functions in Mathematica before ([Buggy behavior of EllipticK with arbitrary precision input and $MinPrecision](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/143966/buggy-behavior-of-elliptick-with-arbitrary-precision-input-and-minprecision)).

Are others seeing this issue as well?

Comment: Which version are you running? Works fine for me on 12.1.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 9, 2020)

Comment: My version is `"13.2.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (November 18, 2022)"` and I can repeat the behaviour. For a workaround, just ``EllipticE[0.0, 0.8`7]``

Comment: I reported this as a bug.