# Inconsistent behaviour of Integrate involving EllipticK?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

```
$Version

Integrate[1/Sqrt[1-x^2+x^4],{x,0,t},Assumptions->t>0]/.t->10.*^5
NIntegrate[1/Sqrt[1-x^2+x^4],{x,0,Infinity}]

Integrate[1/Sqrt[1-x^2+x^4],{x,0,Infinity}]
Out[]//N
```

[image]

The result of `Integrate` + `Limit` agrees with that of `NIntegrate`. But `Integrate` + `N` seems give the wrong result, since the integrand is positive.

This integral is a quite standard elliptic integral. Is it a severe bug of `Integrate`? Any workaround?

see also

[Buggy behavior of EllipticE[0,k] with arbitrary precision input](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/279103/buggy-behavior-of-elliptice0-k-with-arbitrary-precision-input)

[Buggy behavior of EllipticK with arbitrary precision input and $MinPrecision](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/143966/buggy-behavior-of-elliptick-with-arbitrary-precision-input-and-minprecision)

Comment: Apparently a bug in `Limit` and not `Integrate` per se. `In[3]:= InputForm[ii = Integrate[1/Sqrt[1-x^2+x^4],{x,0,t},Assumptions->t>0]]
Out[3]//InputForm= 
-((-1)^(1/6)*Sqrt[1 - (-1)^(1/3)*t^2]*
  Sqrt[(1 + (-1)^(2/3)*t^2)/(1 - t^2 + t^4)]*
  EllipticF[I*ArcSinh[(-1)^(1/3)*t], (-1)^(2/3)])

In[4]:= InputForm[lii = Limit[ii, t->Infinity]]
Out[4]//InputForm= 
(-1)^(1/6)*(Im[EllipticK[(3 - I*Sqrt[3])/2]] - 
  I*Re[EllipticK[(3 - I*Sqrt[3])/2]])

In[5]:= N[lii] 
Out[5]= 0. - 1.68575 I`

Comment: ... which in turn is due to a `Series` glitch. `In[9]:= nss = Normal[Series[ii, {t,Infinity,0}, Assumptions->t>1000]]           

              2/3                   2/3
Out[9]= -((-1)    EllipticK[1 - (-1)   ])

In[10]:= N[nss]                                                                 

                    -16
Out[10]= -2.22045 10    - 1.68575 I
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As shown by @Daniel Lichtblau, this is due to bug of `Limit`, see also `tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation#7441`:

> Definite integrals that involve no singularities are mostly done by taking limits of the indefinite integrals.

> Many other definite integrals are done using Marichev[Dash]Adamchik Mellin transform methods. The results are often initially expressed in terms of Meijer G functions, which are converted into hypergeometric functions using Slater's theorem and then simplified.

Hence a simple workaround is to pull `Infinity` back to finite position, e.g. $x=\tan t$,

```
Inactive[Integrate][1/Sqrt[1-x^2+x^4],{x,0,Infinity}]//
    IntegrateChangeVariables[#,t,t==ArcTan[x]]&//Activate
(*EllipticK[3/4]*)
```